# Don't use blockUI when open bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, blockui

I use jquery BlockUI plugin to lock screen when request is executed. By default i set it for every ajax call. But i also have Bootstrap modals which load data inside using ajax.

```
$(document)
.ajaxStart(function() {
    $.blockUI({
        message: $('#img-loader'),
        css: {
            border: 'none', 
            padding: '5px', 
            'background-color': 'transparent', 
            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
            '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
            opacity: .6, 
            color: '#fff',
            cursor: 'wait'
        }
    });
})
.ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
```

Problem - when i open modal screen become to dark (2 blockUI is applied).
How can i unblockUI when modal is opened (use just Bootstrap background locker)?

What i tried :

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $.unblockUI();
});
```

OR

```
$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
        $.unblockUI();
    });
```

but this didn't work. It seems that BlockUI plugin block screen a bit later.

Comment: Show us the code which does "By default i set it for every ajax call"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're registering a global event handler which triggers for any AJAX call. The code doesn't make a distinction on the context.

Unfortunately, [you can't access the details of the AJAX request from the `ajaxStart` handler](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/). Otherwise, I'd suggest to pass an extra option like `blockUI: true` to the request which the handler would then use.

Instead, you will have to move the code for `$.blockUI({...});` into a helper function (so you don't have to write it every time). You now have to call this helper function every time you make an AJAX call where you want to block the UI. A good place for calling the new helper function is [the `beforeSend` callback](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: I add such function for blockUI : `$.fn.esrbBlockUI = function() {
 $.blockUI({
  message: $('#img-loader'),
  css: {
   border: 'none',
   padding: '5px',
   'background-color': 'transparent',
   '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
   '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
   opacity: .6,
   color: '#fff',
   cursor: 'wait'
  }
 });
}` on every beforeSend in ajax call, but not in every request this block works... get some error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined" in blockUI Library. So don't know what to do

Comment: My first guess would be a problem with `$('#img-loader')`. If that's not it, you will have to get the uncompressed version of blockUI and debug the problem.

Comment: well, yes, it was my fault... now it seems to work alright. And thanks for your answer